# Microsoft Bot Framework not showing attaching file icons and its just showing the name?

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-cognitive-services

I am developing BOT where I am sending some files to bot which seems working but the icon that is appearing in the chat window during send is just the file name rather then icon/logo of respective file extension.

[image]

[image]

So this is how its looking currently.

I want it to look like a rectangle kind of shape with respective icon effect like how any other char platform works.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that is native to the bot framework, mainly because all the channels handle it differently. For example, uploading a document on Teams shows the icon you're looking:

[image: uploaded attachment]

but webchat does not:

[image: webchat attachment]

If you want the icon like the one that appears in Teams to appear in webchat, you're going to have to do it manually. The easiest way to do this is to have a check in your code for a successful upload, and then create a card with the icon, the file name, and an 'upload successful!' message.

Here's a rough idea:

[image: rough card]

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "speak": "<s>Your flight is confirmed for you and 3 other passengers from San Francisco to Amsterdam on Friday, October 10 8:30 AM</s>",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Upload Successful!",
            "weight": "Bolder"
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "separator": true,
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "auto",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "&nbsp;"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/gg1rCqkRVyyJ_wt67HExRIjYf4NvaRYVUXpg3crwUK7joCyVSeYmEJ3EgnLI3QbtX-1ulZYPF_6THsjituT2OG2z",
                            "size": "Small",
                            "spacing": "None"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": 1,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                            "size": "ExtraLarge",
                            "color": "Accent",
                            "text": "cat-2.5.gcode",
                            "spacing": "None"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```